# How to remove an element of an arraylist from input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

how can i remove a student from the course

i tried `enrolledStudents.remove("");`

since the user will have to put the name of the student that previously enrolled to drop him.

```
 public class Course {
  public String courseName;
public int maxNumberofStudentsAllowedtoEnroll=100;
private ArrayList<String> enrolledStudents = new ArrayList<String>(100);


  public Course(String courseName){
    this.courseName = courseName;
  }

  public void addStudent(String student){
  if(enrolledStudents.size() == maxNumberofStudentsAllowedtoEnroll){
    System.out.println("You have reached the maximum numbers of students allowed in a course! \n"
        + "Max allowed: "+maxNumberofStudentsAllowedtoEnroll);
    return;
  }
  enrolledStudents.add(student);
  }

  public int getNumberStudents(){
    return enrolledStudents.size();
  }

  public void showStudents(){
    for(int i=0; i<enrolledStudents.size(); i++){
      System.out.println(enrolledStudents.get(i));
    }
  }

  public void dropStudent(String student){
  enrolledStudents.remove(" ");
  }
```

ive searched up on the net about it. But all the elements of an array are already assigned.

im sorry if im not clear, basically what i want to do is:
if i add a student when i press 1, and then type: "john"
and then do the same with: "albert"

how do i do so that when i press 2 and enter the name of the student to drop, in this case: "john"

So that when I press 3 to view the students only "albert" shows up.

Comment: Did you try `enrolledStudents.remove(student)` ?

Comment: I really don't understand how you came up with `enrolledStudents.remove(" ")`, it makes no sense to me. You already have the students name as a String parameter, but chose to ignore that and pass something completely unrelated to `remove()` instead?

Comment: you guys are right, that was so dumb... Is that i took an into to c++ before and now that im taking java something in my brain took the wrong left and the only thing that looked logical to me was that. But, thanks for feedback! def. not gonna forget something like this!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `""` just write `student`.

```
public void dropStudent(String student){
  enrolledStudents.remove(student);
}
```

that's it. You can check it by calling      `System.out.println(course.enrolledStudents);` before and after `dropStudent` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the quotation marks "" from the .remove method and use the String parameter student inside the remove method.  Below you may find the answer. Hope this helps.

```
public class Course {
  public String courseName;
  public int maxNumberofStudentsAllowedtoEnroll=100;
  private ArrayList<String> enrolledStudents = new ArrayList<String>(100);


  public Course(String courseName){
    this.courseName = courseName;
  }

  public void addStudent(String student){
    if(enrolledStudents.size() == maxNumberofStudentsAllowedtoEnroll){
      System.out.println("You have reached the maximum numbers of students allowed in a course! \n"
        + "Max allowed: "+maxNumberofStudentsAllowedtoEnroll);
    return;
    }
  enrolledStudents.add(student);
  }

  public int getNumberStudents(){
    return enrolledStudents.size();
  }

  public void showStudents(){
    for(int i=0; i<enrolledStudents.size(); i++){
      System.out.println(enrolledStudents.get(i));
    }
  }

  public void dropStudent(String student){
    enrolledStudents.remove(student);
  }
```